# C++ boost asio async_read vs while with two thread

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have two thread which want to push data in and pop data out

```
m_collectThread = std::thread([&] {m_io_service.run();}); 
m_recognizeThread = std::thread([this]{pop();});
```

when data in my_pipe it will trigger push()

```
void test::push()
{
     cout << __func__ << endl;

     boost::asio::async_read(m_pipe, boost::asio::buffer(m_buf),
            boost::asio::transfer_all(),
            boost::bind(&test::push,
            this,   /* add this if bind class member function */
            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
            boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

and pop() always run (bad idea?

```
void test::pop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        cout << __func__ << endl;
        usleep(200);
    }
}
```

two thread run well at the begin, but after awhile push() get the less chance to get in

out put like:


begin:

> push
>
> pop
>
> push
>
> pop

**later**

> push
>
> pop
>
> pop
>
> pop
>
> pop
>
> pop
>
> push
>
> pop
>
> pop
>
> pop
>
> pop
>
> pop

This is not what I want, how can I make it better?

---

[Edit]


I Found out the source of m_pipe was an audio stream and put data for 32 bytes/ms.

The rough way to avoid always pop is sleep longer in pop().

But it is really not efficient...

Answer (score 0):

> ### **WARNING**
>
> This answer does *not* address the biggest potential bug in the code (not shown), because you are not indicating any thread synchronization (locks) around `m_buf` (and other members?).
>
> That would mean you are using shared resources from multiple threads  simultaneously. If you do that, that's a [Data Race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and leads to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Yes, the tight loop is a bad idea.

With the code like:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/620a42960bc4ba07)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

namespace ba = boost::asio;

struct Test {
    ba::io_service m_io_service;
    boost::optional<ba::io_service::work> m_work { m_io_service };
    std::thread m_collectThread {[&] {m_io_service.run();}}; 
    std::thread m_recognizeThread {[this]{pop();}};

    ba::ip::tcp::socket m_pipe { m_io_service };
    char m_buf[4];

    Test() {
        m_pipe.connect({{}, 6767});
        push();
    }

    void push(boost::system::error_code ec = {}, size_t = 0)
    {
        std::cout << __func__ << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;

        if (ec) return;

        using namespace ba::placeholders;
        ba::async_read(m_pipe,
                ba::buffer(m_buf),
                ba::transfer_all(),
                boost::bind(&Test::push, this, error, bytes_transferred));
    }

    void pop()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;
            usleep(200);
        }
    }

    ~Test() {
        m_work.reset();
        if (m_recognizeThread.joinable())
            m_recognizeThread.join();
        if (m_collectThread.joinable())
            m_collectThread.join();
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t;
}
```

I run a server that says "HELLO" every 100ms:

```
for a in {1..100}; do sleep .1; netcat -l -p 6868 <<< HELLO; done
```

Then you can see, by running the program like `./sotest | uniq -c`:

```
      3 pop
      1 push Success
   1074 pop
      1 push Success
   3681 pop
      2 push Success
   3701 pop
      1 push Success
   3689 pop
      2 push Success
   3687 pop
      1 push Success
   3705 pop
      1 push pop
```

You can see, for every push there are thousands of pops. That's inefficient.

## QUEUING

Why don't you just use queuing?

Queues are the natural solution here unless you need ultra-low latency or extreme throughput (in which case lock-free queues are the next logical step).

In fact, `io_service` **is** a queue, so you can simply do: **Live On Coliru**

In fact, I'd further simplify and remove the other thread and the `work`:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace ba = boost::asio;

struct Test {
    ba::io_service& m_io_service;
    ba::ip::tcp::socket m_pipe { m_io_service };
    char m_buf[4];

    Test(ba::io_service& io) : m_io_service(io) {
        m_pipe.connect({{}, 6767});
        read_loop();
    }

    void push(size_t len) {
        std::cout << __func__ << std::endl;

        m_io_service.post(
            boost::bind(&Test::handle_message, this, std::string(m_buf, len)));
    }

    void read_loop() {
        using namespace ba::placeholders;
        ba::async_read(m_pipe,
                ba::buffer(m_buf),
                ba::transfer_all(),
                boost::bind(&Test::on_received, this, error, bytes_transferred));
    }

    void on_received(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t len) {
        if (len) push(len);
        if (!ec) read_loop();
    }

    void handle_message(std::string const& data) {
        std::cout << "Handling '" << data << "'\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    ba::io_service io;
    Test t(io);

    io.run();
}
```

Comment: Because if there is no more data form m_pipe,  the data already received can't be read ? Or I misunderstood something ?

Comment: Yes you misunderstood. Of course `work` doesn't block.  You can find that in the documentation,  or you could just look at the output of the program.

Comment: In fact, if you try without that `work` instance it will not work at all since the `io_service ::run` could complete before any `async_*` operation is ever posted. That's the reason i added it (and also the rain that `Io_service::work` exists